# Restart/Theme Switch Feature for PyQt5 Application

Tags: python, pyqt5, desktop-application, pyside2

I implemented a theme switch feature, which restarts the application using **subprocess** and sends a sys variable indicating the desired theme, so that the main controller can know which styles to apply for the application components.

**styles_controller.py**

```
def switch_theme(app):
    app.quit()
    if (not dark_mode):
        subprocess.Popen(['python', 'main.py', 'dark'])
    else:
        subprocess.Popen(['python', 'mainp.py', 'light'])
```

Currently, this implementation works as desired, but my question is, if
I create an executable for the application, will this implementation work on both Windows and Linux, will it even work ? What are some better ways to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting the script to executable then it is not necessary to use "python" as a program but the executable itself, also the script is not necessary. So you have to differentiate if it is an executable or a script and in the case of pyinstaller you must use the `sys.frozen` attribute. Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
def switch_theme(theme):
    args = [sys.executable]
    if not getattr(sys, "frozen", False):
        args.append("main.py")
    args.append(theme)
    subprocess.Popen(args)


def restart():
    QCoreApplication.quit()
    switch_theme("dark" if dark_mode else "light")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Does that mean in case of an executable, I should replace main.py with the .exe file ?

Comment: @on98 No, when you use .py the executable is python: `python your_script.py dark` but when you convert it to executable the same application is the executable: `your_executable dark`

Comment: Thanks for answer